# evaluating inverse in octave

Tags: octave

I am new to octave. I was asked to write a function [k,y,info]=ivs(a,b,fun,N) which computes the approximated values of the inverse of a given univariate function: fun:[a,b] -- >R; over N equidistant points over the interval [fun(a),fun(b)] (or [fun(b),fun(a)]). 
y is the result
k - vector of aprroximated values of inverse function (evaluated over equidistant points)
y - vector of equidistant points 
info - 0 if computation ended with success, not 0 otherwise

I wrote some code, it does not work, I get a lot of errors, but I cannot find out from them whats wrong. I expect to be a lot of mistakes in this code. I would like someone to point out whats wrong.

```
function [k,y,info]=ivs(a,b,fun,N)
  if(a-b==0)
  error('computation cannot take place, a=b');
  else
    if(fun(a)=fun(b))
      error('we have a problem, interval is zero length')
    end
    if(fun(a)<fun(b))
    x=linspace(fun(a), fun(b), N);
      for l in 1:N
      [j,FS,info,out]=fzero(@(j) fun(j)-x(l),[f(a),f(b)]);
      y(i)=j;
        if(info!=1)
        error("Something went wrong with fzero()");
        end
      end
    else
    x=linspace(fun(b), fun(a), N);
      for l in 1:N
      [j,FS,info,out]=fzero(@(j) fun(j)-x(l),[f(a),f(b)]);
      y(l)=j;
        if(info!=1)
        warning("Something went wrong with fzero()");
        end
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you edit your post with some of the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in the typing, but also in the logic

you are declaring a `k` output but never creating it.
`fun(a)=fun(b)` is an assignment not a test.
`for l in 1:N` is NOT the correct way for a `for`.
you are using `l` for the cycle and than using `i` to index `y`.
in calling `fzero` the interval where to look for the solution is NOT `[f(a),f(b)]`.

Amendig these problems, I guess your function was supposed to be:

```
function [k,y,info]=ltrigp(a,b,fun,N)
  if(a-b==0)
  error('computation cannot take place, a=b');
  else
    if(fun(a)==fun(b))
      error('we have a problem, interval is zero length')
    end
    if(fun(a)<fun(b))
    x=linspace(fun(a), fun(b), N);
      for l =  1:N
      [j,FS,info,out]=fzero(@(j) fun(j)-x(l),[a,b]);
      y(l)=j;
      k(l)=x(l);
        if(info!=1)
        error("Something went wrong with fzero()");
        end
      end
    else
    x=linspace(fun(b), fun(a), N);
      for l = 1:N
      [j,FS,info,out]=fzero(@(j) fun(j)-x(l),[a,b]);
      y(l)=j;
      k(l)=x(l);
        if(info!=1)
        warning("Something went wrong with fzero()");
        end
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

and work like this:

```
a=1;
b=4;
N=10;

[k,y,info]=ltrigp(a,b,@exp,N)
k =

 Columns 1 through 8:

    2.7183    8.4827   14.2471   20.0116   25.7760   31.5404   37.3049   43.0693

 Columns 9 and 10:

   48.8337   54.5982

y =

 Columns 1 through 8:

   1.0000   2.1380   2.6566   2.9963   3.2494   3.4513   3.6191   3.7628

 Columns 9 and 10:

   3.8884   4.0000

info =  1
```